# Excel 2013 default format is Date when adding a new sheet - how to change to General?

Tags: excel

I have a complicated Excel workbook and for some reason, when I add a new sheet, the default format for the cells is Date and not General as is the case in my other Excel files. How do I fix it so if I add a new sheet, the default format is General? It's only this workbook. If I open a new excel file or even add sheets to other excel files, the default format is General.

Comment: @pnuts You  are probably correct, but it is an old and well documented issue

Comment: OK, so I'm kind of new around here. Help me out, why is this off topic? And I did search, on this site and on the Internet and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @pnuts That's true.  But the fix is so simple ...

Comment: @pnuts  Point taken.

Comment: @pnuts Not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported off and on for many years.  For reasons unclear, the Normal cell style gets modified to date.  So go to the Home Ribbon and, on the Styles tab, right-click on `Normal` and select Modify.  Change it back to `General`

Comment: I've always suspected its bad timed hotkey. Excel is eager to change formats to date when date like numbers are inserted and I think the user somehow saves it as default.